# How to retrieve the path of a process with Get-Process or Get-CimInstance in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I want to extract the path of the processes but actually this property is not set when I call the GEt-Process for my ID. For some other processes the property is set but not for all

Here is my command

```
Get-Process -id 18628| Select-Object path
```

This results in

[image]

I have also tried to retrieve the path with get-cimInstance

```
GEt-CimInstance -ClassName win32_process -Filter "name like java%'
```

[image]

I have multiple process with the same name, I want to see the detailed call of that so I want to see which path is called. Is there a way so achieve this in powershell?

Comment: `Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_process -Filter "name like 'java%'" |Select Path`

Comment: Likely a permissions issue, try running the same cmds with elevated privileges